# A sequence satisfy the recursive relation: $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_n}{1+a_{n+1}}$ ,$a_0=1,a_1=x$,At what value of x does $a_n$ converge?

Tags: analysis

It's obviously that when x is unequal to $0.737338……$ ,${a_n}$ has two limit points ,and one is zero.set f(x) is a limit point of $a_n$ and unequal to zero,there are some approximate value of f(x)

f(0.737)=3.12907e-4

f(0.8)=0.0580494

f(1)=0.244534

f(2)=1.19531

f(3)=2.16334

f(4)=3.14053

f(1000)=999.001

Comment: $\{a_n\}$ has only one limit which is zero.

Comment: Even terms and odd terms converge to different values.